# C# struct new StructType() vs default(StructType)

Tags: c#, struct

Say I have a struct

```
public struct Foo
{
    ...
}
```

Is there any difference between

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

and

```
Foo foo = default(Foo);
```

?

Comment: Very interesting, Ani. Jon Skeet's article says that the constructor is not called when using a *generic* `default(T)`. Does anybody know how it would behave with a non-generic `default(Foo)`? I'm guessing the constructor would be called by `default(Foo)`.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You might wonder why, if they are exactly the same, there are two ways to do the same thing.

They are not quite the same because *every reference type or value type is guaranteed to have a default value* but not every reference type is guaranteed to have a parameterless constructor:

```
static T MakeDefault<T>()
{
    return default(T); // legal
    // return new T(); // illegal
}
```

---

UPDATE from 2023:  A commenter notes that this answer is out of date; in C# 10, `new S()` for a struct type `S` initializes struct fields to their default values, `default(S)` initializes them to zeros, so there *is* a difference now. The answer above however still stands; it is not legal to do `new T()` on a type parameter `T` unless it is constrained to have a constructor.

Comment: @Ani: See the specification. It is stated explicitly there, and copied in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974063/c-struct-new-structtype-vs-defaultstructtype/4974174#4974174).

Comment: @Jason: With regard to the spec - with reflection you can actually tell the difference between a struct that has a default ctor and one that doesn't. So at that level, the struct may not even *have* a ctor. Perhaps the spec might be telling us a 'soft lie'? (what I'm saying might be utter nonsense; hope Eric can clarify).

Comment: I hate to contest a Lippert answer, but the scope here is a little more general than the question; the OP asked about structs, specifically. If I'm not mistaken, `static T MakeDefault<T>() where T : struct { return new T(); }` is legal... so is it different?

Comment: @BenMosher: In that case `new T()` and `default(T)` are the same and the compiler will generate the same code for both.

Comment: @EricLippert With "struct field initializers" introduced in C# 10.0, `new T()` will return a struct with the fields initialized according to their initializers, and `default(T)` will set the fields to zero (https://dotnetfiddle.net/NnWDfT).

Comment: @GSerg: Though that is true, my answer is specifically about the case where T is generic. However you make a good point; I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 18):

No, both expressions will yield the same exact result.

Since structs cannot contain explicit parameterless constructors (i.e. you cannot define one yourself) the default constructor will give you a version of the struct with all values zero'd out. This is the same behavior that `default` gives you as well.

Comment: +1 I tried just now, the two expressions generated the same IL.

Comment: They generate different IL if a paramterless ctor were present; see my answer.

Answer (score 14):

For value-types, the options are,  *practically* speaking, equivalent.

However, I was intrigued by Jon Skeet's [empirical research](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/12/10/value-types-and-parameterless-constructors/) into which 'instructions' result in the invocation of a struct's parameterless default constructor when it is  specified in CIL (you can't do it in C# because it doesn't let you). Amongst other things, he'd tried out `default(T)` and `new T()` where `T` is a type parameter. They appeared equivalent; neither of them appeared to call the constructor.

But the one case (it appears) he hadn't tried was  `default(Foo)` where `Foo` is an actual 
struct type.

So I took his code for the 'hacked' struct and tried that out for myself.

---

**It turns out that default(Foo) doesn't call the constructor, whereas new Foo() in fact does.**

Using a struct type `Oddity` that specifies a parameterless constructor:

**With optimizations turned off**, the method:

```
private void CallDefault()
{
    Oddity a = default(Oddity);
}
```

produces the CIL (without `nop`s, `ret`s etc.):

```
L_0001: ldloca.s a
L_0003: initobj [Oddity]Oddity
```

whereas the method:

```
private void CallNew()
{
    Oddity b = new Oddity();
}
```

produces:

```
L_0001: ldloca.s b
L_0003: call instance void [Oddity]Oddity::.ctor()
```

**With optimizations turned on**, the compiler appears to optimize away pretty much *all* of the `CallDefault` method into a no-op, but *keeps* the call to the constructor in `CallNew` (for potential side-effects?).

Answer (score 13):

The language specification (§4.1.2 and §5.2) is your friend. Specifically:

> For a variable of a *value-type*, the default value is the same as the value computed by the *value-type*’s default constructor (§4.1.2).

(Italics in original.)

Note that this is not the same for reference types.

> For a variable of a reference-type, the default value is `null`.

This is emphatically different than the value produced by a default constructor, if one exists.

Answer (score 5):

`default` keyword is useful when you do not know exact type and it works not only for structs, for example in generics:

```
T FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if (...source is empty...) return default(T);
}
```

This will return null for reference types, default value for primitive types(0 for numbers, false for bool), defaultly inialized structure, etc ...

When type is known at compile-time it makes no sense to use `default`, you can use `new Foo()` instead

Answer (score 2):

Small update with the freshly (C# 10) introduced [Parameterless constructors and field initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#parameterless-constructors-and-field-initializers). `default(MyStruct)` and `new MyStruct` are **not** the same anymore.

```cs
new MyStruct().PrintToConsole();    // Prints 10
default(MyStruct).PrintToConsole(); // Prints 0

public struct MyStruct
{
    private int anyNumber;
    
    public MyStruct()
    {
        anyNumber = 10;
    }
    
    public void PrintToConsole() => System.Console.WriteLine($"My number is: {anyNumber}");
}
```

If you want to fiddle around on your own [here you go](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0BdQBc)