# C# what is the difference between new 'Classname' and default('classname')

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and not very familiar with it. I am confused with the difference of `new PostpaidProfile();` and `default(AutoliftResult);` What I mean is what is the difference on how they are call. Below is the classes or object I don't know too what they are called

```
public class PostpaidProfile
    {

        public bool WasRetrieved { get; set; }

        public string AccountCategory { get; set; }

        public string AccountNum { get; set; }

        public string Acd { get; set; }

        public string ActivationDate { get; set; }

        public int? AgingDays { get; set; }

        public decimal? CreditRating { get; set; }

        public string CutOff { get; set; }

        public string Cycle { get; set; }

        public bool? IsBlacklisted { get; set; }

        public bool? IsNopsa { get; set; }

        public decimal? Msf { get; set; }

        public string RatePlan { get; set; }

        public string ServiceStatus { get; set; }

        public int? VipCode { get; set; }

        public string Zip { get; set; }

        public string Remarks { get; set; }

    }

    public class AutoliftResult
    {

        public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }

        public decimal StatusCode { get; set; }

        public string Message { get; set; }

        public string SRNumber { get; set; }

    }
```

and here how they are called

```
PostpaidProfile output = new PostpaidProfile();

AutoliftResult output = default(AutoliftResult);
```

My question is what are their difference? (im not talking about their content) is it the same if I declare `AutoliftResult output = new AutoliftResult();`

Comment: maybe you'd rather ask difference against `PostpaidProfile output = null`

Comment: you need to read about new and default operator of c#. please see this link for more info. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974063/c-sharp-struct-new-structtype-vs-defaultstructtype

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`new PostpaidProfile()` creates a new instance of the class.

`default(AutoliftResult)` creates a default value for the specified type.  For reference types, it is `null`.  For value types, it is usually whatever `0` translates to for the type - i.e. if type is `int`, default value is `0`; if type is `bool`, default value is `false`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> default keyword will return null for reference types and zero for numeric value types.

Please note it will return zero for numeric value types and NOT all value types. For example, for `struct` types, even though they are value types, it will return the name of the struct and not zero. See fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ozSbwC).

In your case `PostpaidProfile output = new PostpaidProfile()` will return an instance and `default` will return null.

If you do this it will result in an exception because `output` is null:

```
AutoliftResult output = default(AutoliftResult);
output.IsSuccess; // will not work
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/generics/default-keyword-in-generic-code).